# Playframework with Deadbolt2: overriding method getSubject in trait DeadboltHandler of type

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, playframework-2.3, deadbolt-2

I am using `Deadbolt2` for authorization. When i, `extends` `DeadboltHandler`  and override their methods, i am getting following error in eclipse:

```
implements be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.DeadboltHandler.getSubject
overriding method getSubject in trait DeadboltHandler of type [A](request: play.api.mvc.Request[A])Option[be.objectify.deadbolt.core.models.Subject]; method getSubject has incompatible type
```

These are compile time errors and produce on `getSubject` method, because of its return type. I declare its return type as `Future[Option[Subject]]` and when i use `Option[Subject]` as a return type, the errors is removed. When i saw example by `steve` https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala-examples/blob/master/app/security/MyDeadboltHandler.scala, he used `Future[Option[Subject]]` and there is no error in code when i import code in eclipse. When i compile the code using `activator clean compile` command there is no compile time error.

CODE:

```
override def getSubject[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Option[Subject]] = {
println("Method Start getSubject");
if(!request.headers.get("userId").isEmpty){
   println("If Method Start getSubject");
  val userId = request.headers.get("userId").get;
  userDao.findById(BSONObjectID.apply(userId));
}else{
  println("Else Method Start getSubject");
  Future(Option.empty);
}}
```

**Update**

When i am using deadbolt `be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-scala" % "2.3.2` dependency version, i got compile time error in eclipse and build run successfully. But when i use `be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-scala" % "2.3.3` dependency version i am getting build error also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of getSubject changed in 2.3.3 because the integration with the view layer is flawed.  The examples also need updating.

In v2.4 (both Java and Scala versions), all interfaces will return Futures and when blocking calls are needed, e.g. by template restrictions, there will be adapters for the interfaces as required with automatic wrapping.

See the 2.3.3 release notes in the README of https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala - specifically, this bit

> DeadboltHandler#getSubject returns an Option[Subject] in place of an Future[Option[Subject]]. Where the subject is needed, the internal code will take care of wrapping the call in a Future.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks @Steve for you information, but according to my requirements, i need to return future instead of Option. Please click on this link, which help you to explain my requirements, or i think, this is not only my. https://github.com/harmeetsingh0013/playframework-dynamic-authorization-using-deadbolt2/blob/master/app/handlers/MyDeadboltHandler.scala

Comment: You can always use v2.3.2 - it has the same feature set, but uses Futures.

Comment: Ok @Steve i understand, but the fact is that, like my example, if some need to used `reactive-mongo`, then without futures, this cause the problem. Please correct me, if i am wrong?

Comment: I think I'm maybe not understanding your question.  The base difference here is, for all user-implemented interfaces: **2.3.2** uses Futures, e.g. `Future[Option[Subject]]`   **2.3.3** does not use Futures, e.g. `Option[Subject]`

Comment: yes @Steve i understand the main difference. But the question is that, if i want to use `reactive-mongo` and return the user from database,` reactive mongo` return the  result in future. As i am using in my example: https://github.com/harmeetsingh0013/playframework-dynamic-authorization-using-deadbolt2/blob/master/app/handlers/MyDeadboltHandler.scala. But how we use, Reactive mongo with **2.3.3** version ?

Comment: The only way to use 2.3.3 with reactive mongo is to collapse the future down to a result and return that, which removes the benefit of non-blocking DB.  I suggest you stick with 2.3.2 for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76900/discussion-between-harmeet-singh-taara-and-steve-chaloner).

Comment: Thanks @Steve. But i thought this was not good changes in version 2.3.3, because most of the time, mostly developers need to write non-blocking code. What do you think ?

Comment: It was a good change because it brought Deadbolt 2.3.3 back in line with the other 2.3.x releases.  A redesigned approach to asynchronous activity will appear in 2.4.0, which will remain consistent from the first release.

Comment: Oh you means, our deabolt **2.3.2** only support `Future` other **2.3.x** not?

Comment: Yes, it was a blip that shouldn't have happened.

Comment: Thanks @Steve and your blip really helped us :).